# How do I get an element to ignore another's margin, or remove that margin?

Tags: html, css, layout

Another quite simple problem which is turning out to be rather a nuisance. If I'm doing/missing something that's idiotic feel free to lay it on me :)

**Explanation:**

I have a website in progress of being made (a project for school) and I'm trying to get a 'News Column' on the right-hand side of each page. I've managed to create it, however on one page it's being affected by another element's margin. Look at the following:

http://puu.sh/o5UXs.png - This is the margin on the right that's restricting the News Column from being in that position.

http://puu.sh/o5UYD.png - This is the complete News Column (currently, as data can be added to the database).

I was to have the News Column be alongside it.

**My Current CSS:**

http://puu.sh/o5Vb1.png

Hope someone can help,

Jake

Comment: Share your `codes` !

Answer (score 1):

You can use *position: absolute* or *position: fixed*.

> Sometimes adding negative margin to an element may cause it to ignore another element's margin, but I **don't** recommend it.

---

Read this [resource](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), it'll help you.